# Custom keyboard for input in a custom uitableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I have a view which contains a tableview, (i call this view the EquationView, and its controller the EquationViewController).  The table view cells are custom cells with a label and a textfield, representing a variable and its value, receptively.  I have been able to get my custom keyboard to apear when editing begins in the textfield.

However, I haven't been able to get the keystrokes to apear in the correct cell, do to the fact that I haven't been able figure out how to send the indexPath of the cell with textfield being edited to the custom keyboard controller class. I have included my EquationViewController.h file in my custom keyboard controller class and have been able to change the text in the tableview's textFields by manually setting the indexPath to a specified row.  Here is the keyboard class definition:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "EquationViewController.h"


@interface CustomNumberPadViewController : UIViewController {
    EquationViewController *equationViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) EquationViewController *equationViewController;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

My action method looks like this (so far):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    VariableCell *cell = (VariableCell *)[equationDetailViewController.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

    cell.variableValue.text = @"test";

}
```

This get the word "test" to appear on whichever row I set in the index path.

So what I'm wondering is, is there a way to pass/get the indexPath of the cell whose textField is being edited to the action method in my custom keyboard controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set your UIViewController as the delegate of your UITextFields and catch the textFieldDidBegin: delegate method?

Comment: Your right, that was the way to go.  I had forgotten to connect the delegate in IB.  I ended up declaring a variable, (selectedTextfieldRow) inside my EquationViewController.  I then assigned tags to each field according to the row they are on in the tableview.  Then in textFieldDidBegin I assign the tag number to the selectedTextfieldRow variable.  Then in the action method in the keyboard controller I retrieve the selectedTextfieldRow value and use it as my row for the index path in calling the selected cell.  It seems kind of round about, but it works.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You also can store your UITextField in your ivar directly instead of using the tag. If you then need the indexPath, you can go up its superviews to find the cell (e.g. textField.superview.superview if textField is in the contentView of the UITableViewCell) and use UITableView's `indexPathForCell` to get the indexPath. But it's up to you depending on your needs